# How to use sigsuspend() in C (usr_interrupt undeclared)

Tags: c, process, gnu

I'm trying to use `sigsuspend` to make a process wait for a signal sent by his child. The problem is that when I try to compile the code, `usr_interupt` seems to be undeclared. What am I doing wrong? I think I'm following strictly the GNU manual

Fathers code:

```
sigemptyset (&mask);
sigaddset (&mask, SIGUSR2); 

sigprocmask (SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &oldmask);
while (!usr_interrupt)
    sigsuspend (&oldmask); 
sigprocmask (SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, NULL);
```

Child code:

```
kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
```

Comment: From the code you posted, can't find what `usr_interrupt` does or where it's declared .

Comment: That's my question. I didn't know usr_interrupt needed to be declared here.

Comment: Both `sigsuspend()` and `usr_interrupt` are incorrect. You can replace the while loop with one using [`sigwaitinfo()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigwaitinfo.2.html) instead. Also, you should apply the signal mask before forking the child process.

Comment: Code is verbatim from the [glibc documentation on `sigsuspend`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sigsuspend.html#Sigsuspend). It is following up on the previous sections of the documentation. `usr_interrupt` comes from an earlier example in one of the previous sections. See `can replace [...] in the previous section`. You will need to read it top to bottom to understand the examples in detail.

Comment: Source: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sigsuspend.html#Sigsuspend

Comment: @NominalAnimal The example Alejandro is working from was written at a time when `sigwaitinfo` was not universally available.  It should probably be updated.  (This applies to an awful lot of the example code in the glibc manual: good advice for 1995, but many of the portability problems they're working around are no longer relevant.)

Comment: Okay, I worded myself badly (me fail English) above. Reworded: `sigsuspend()` and `usr_interrupt` are the wrong solution to the stated problem of *"make a process wait for a signal sent by [a child process]"*. The correct solution to that is `sigwaitinfo()`/`sigtimedwait()`. The purpose of `sigsuspend()` is to block until one of the signals in the specified mask becomes pending (deliverable, but not delivered yet), while allowing other signals to be delivered to their respective signal handlers.  Not the correct tool for the stated use case.